# Trying to index an array based on a variable. But when it's zero, nothing happens

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to access my "state" array based on the 9th digit of the "CPF" Variable. When the 9th digit is ZERO, nothing is printed. **Otherwise, it works fine.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){
    char state[10][100] = {"Rio Grande do Sul", "Distrito Federal, Goias, Mato Grosso, Mato Grosso do Sul ou Tocantins", "Amazonas, Para, Roraima, Amapa, Acre ou Rondonia", "Ceara, Maranhao e Piaui", "Paraiba, Pernambuco, Alagoas ou Rio Grande do Norte", "Bahia ou Sergipe", "Minas Gerais", "Rio de Janeiro ou Espirito Santo", "Sao Paulo", "Parana ou Santa Catarina"};
    
    char cpf[11];
    printf("Enter a CPF: ");
    scanf("%s", cpf);
    int digit = (int)(cpf[8])-48; 

    printf("STATE: %s",state[digit]);
    return 0;
    
}
```

The digit value will tell me the state that the person lives. After turning the 9th digit of cpf into `int`, I subtracted 48 because of the ascii table (0-9)

Example of states:

`state[0]= Rio Grande do Sul` <-- Nothing shows

`state[1]= Distrito Federal, Goias, Mato Grosso, Mato Grosso do Sul ou Tocantins` <-- Ok

...

`state[9]= Parana ou Santa Catarina`

Example of inputs and outputs:

CPF = 00000000100

`Distrito Federal, Goias, Mato Grosso, Mato Grosso do Sul ou Tocantins`

CPF = 00000000900

`Parana ou Santa Catarina`

CPF = 00000000000

Comment: You have a buffer overflow thanks to not passing `scanf()` a char array long enough to hold the string it's reading.

Comment: https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Try checking the return value of `scanf`?

Comment: Arthur Brenno, Change `char cpf[11]; ...  scanf("%s", cpf);` --> `char cpf[100]; ... scanf("%99s", cpf);`  Never use `"%s"` in `scanf()` without a _width_.

Comment: @doctorlove Won't prevent the program from potentially crashing.

Comment: @Lundin true - just drawing attention to the can of worms this opens